# Why Can This Window Still Be Resized, Minimized, and Maximized?

Tags: c#, wpf, window-resize

I have a window in an application, and the Resize mode is set to NoResize, but if you click the top-left of the window, the menu items of "Maximize", "Minimize", and "Size" are still enabled. This only happens to my windows that has no icon but still has the close button. Meaning this problem isn't happening to my windows that do have an icon.

This is the code that is removing the icon but still keeps the red close button:

```
protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e) {
    IconHelper.RemoveIcon(this);
}

public static class IconHelper {
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hwnd, int index);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hwnd, int index, int newStyle);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr hwndInsertAfter, int x, int y, int width, int height, uint flags);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hwnd, uint msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    const int GWL_EXSTYLE = -20;
    const int WS_EX_DLGMODALFRAME = 0x0001;
    const int SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001;
    const int SWP_NOMOVE = 0x0002;
    const int SWP_NOZORDER = 0x0004;
    const int SWP_FRAMECHANGED = 0x0020;
    const uint WM_SETICON = 0x0080;

    public static void RemoveIcon(Window window) {
        IntPtr hwnd = new WindowInteropHelper(window).Handle;
        int extendedStyle = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE);
        SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, extendedStyle | WS_EX_DLGMODALFRAME);
        SetWindowPos(hwnd, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_FRAMECHANGED);
    }
}
```

[image]

I would like to know why this is happening and would appreciate it if some one can fix this problem. I am using WPF and C#.

Comment: It works for me. I can't help you fix your code without seeing it.

Comment: Note that minimize will always be there.

Comment: @ChristianStewart It is disabled for me.

Comment: @KendallFrey Huh. Never knew you could prevent minimizing

Comment: The code which causes the problem. (Hint: Try to reproduce it on a small test project.)

Comment: I have the same problem (C++ Win32) when I use `WS_EX_DLGMODALFRAME` with window style that doesn't have "resize","minimize" and "maximize" button, such as `WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW & ~(WS_SIZEBOX | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX)`, but if you enable 'minimize' button it will work just fine, seems like a bug for me.